# Specific all static files which is same directory level as app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine

[image]

I have all static files same directory as my `app.yaml`

Now, I have to specific the static files **one by one** in my `app.yaml`

```
application: xxx
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /style.css
  static_files: style.css
  upload: style.css

- url: /android.png
  static_files: android.png
  upload: android.png

- url: /logo.png
  static_files: logo.png
  upload: logo.png

- url: /helloworld.py
  script: helloworld.py
```

Is there any easier way for me to specific all my static files? (Provide they are same directory level as `app.yaml`)

I try

```
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  static_dir: \.
  upload: index.html
```

It won't work.

```
Fatal error when loading application configuration:
Unexpected attribute "static_dir" for mapping type static_files.
  in "C:\Projects\xxx-website\app.yaml", line 12, column 1
```

Comment: Why do you want all of your static files in the same directory with app.yaml? This seems like an artificial restriction that's just going to annoy you.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this." "Don't do that then."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others suggested you can put your files in the static folder and have an app.yaml that looks like this (so you don't have to enter manually every file):
https://gist.github.com/3031499

You can also specific handlers at the top like:

```
- url: /counter
  script: counter.app

- url: /(.*\.rar)
  script: download.app
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason to try and do this? Place them all in the static directory.